# Individual lightning Dashboard access to users

Tags: lightning, reporting, security, sharing, dashboard

I have a requirement where there are specific users who should have view access only to few dashboards in a folder but not all.

I know that we can manage folder access but is there any way we can manage individual dashboard sharing access as well. I could not find any option on how to control sharing access to individual dashboard in a folder.

Please suggest